# How to insert kernel module from userspace app?

Tags: kernel, kernel-module

I am looking for one thing:

How can i insert kernel module from userspace program? can anyone please provide me any example related to this scenario?

Thanks

**Raheel**

Answer (score 1):

After a little search, I found that there's a system call named

```
#include <linux/module.h>
int init_module(const char *name, struct module *image);
```

You can take a look at this man page if you want further details.
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/init_module.2.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Adel C Kod,
I just resolved that issue, here I am posting a simple sample code:

```
char cmnd[10];

if (strcmp(cmnd, "insert")==0) {
  system ("/sbin/insmod /home/xyzUBUNtu/Desktop/MyMod/kernel1.ko");
  printf("Your Module inserted");
  return 1;
}
```

thanks

Raheel..

Comment: Actually, that's the answer that occurred to me at first(see my edited post); but wasn't sure it'd work or not. 
Glad it worked :D

Comment: Oh and accept one of the answers, if the question is solved ;)